# Error while upgrading ODOO from V11 to V12

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12, erp

While migrating my ODOO from version 11 to 12 using openUpgrade, I've encountered the following issue. I am using the community version of ODOO.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/user/company/version12/OpenUpgrade/odoo/service/server.py", line 1162, in preload_registries
     registry = Registry.new(dbname, update_module=update_module)
   File "/home/user/company/version12/OpenUpgrade/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
     odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
   File "/home/user/company/version12/OpenUpgrade/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 478, in load_modules
     processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
   File "/home/user/company/version12/OpenUpgrade/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 361, in load_marked_modules
     loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
   File "/home/user/company/version12/OpenUpgrade/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 196, in load_module_graph
     load_openerp_module(package.name)
   File "/home/user/company/version12/OpenUpgrade/odoo/modules/module.py", line 368, in load_openerp_module
     __import__('odoo.addons.' + module_name)
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
   File "/home/user/company/version12/OpenUpgrade/odoo/modules/module.py", line 82, in load_module
     exec(open(modfile, 'rb').read(), new_mod.__dict__)
   File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
   File "/home/user/company/erp12/company-erp-v3/mail_trail_message/models/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
     from . import mail_thread
   File "/home/user/company/erp12/company-erp-v3/mail_trail_message/models/mail_thread.py", line 33, in <module>
     class MailThread(models.AbstractModel):
   File "/home/user/company/version12/OpenUpgrade/odoo/api.py", line 112, in _new_
     value = guess(value)
   File "/home/user/company/version12/OpenUpgrade/odoo/api.py", line 690, in guess
     args, vname, kwname, defaults = getargspec(method)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/inspect.py", line 1095, in getargspec
     raise ValueError("Function has keyword-only parameters or annotations"
 ValueError: Function has keyword-only parameters or annotations, use inspect.signature() API which can support them
```

Answer (score 0):

`File "/home/user/company/erp12/company-erp-v3/mail_trail_message/models/mail_thread.py", line 33, in <module>`

This is where you should look at. I believe Odoo has no module name mail_trail_message